# There's any way to load @ImportResources dynamically by checking the active profile that's running?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have this class below ... it's responsible for start my application , is there any
maneuver to make @ImportResources annotation dynamic?
For my test covering I would like to load another resource. I am trying to avoid to run my unit test with my parallel configuration, because the results are being intermittent.

```
    import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
    import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
    
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.NoopHostnameVerifier;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
    import org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContextBuilder;
    import org.apache.http.ssl.TrustStrategy;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;
    import org.springframework.http.client.BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory;
    import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
    import org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean;
    import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
    
    import br.com.bradesco.ciar.srv.agorainv.infrastructure.LoggingClientHttpRequestInterceptor;
    
    @SpringBootApplication
    @ImportResource("spring/*.xml")
    public class Application {
    
        @Value("${rest.timeout.read}")
        private int readTimeout;
        @Value("${rest.timeout.connect}")
        private int connectTimeout;
    
        public static void main(final String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        }
    
        @Bean
        public HttpClient httpClient() {
            try {
                return HttpClients.custom().setSSLHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE)
                        .setSSLContext(new SSLContextBuilder().loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustStrategy() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean isTrusted(final X509Certificate[] arg0, final String arg1) throws CertificateException {
                                return true;
                            }
                        }).build()).build();
            }
            catch (final Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    
        @Bean
        public HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory() {
            final HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient());
            requestFactory.setReadTimeout(readTimeout);
            requestFactory.setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout);
            return requestFactory;
        }
    
        @Bean
        public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
            final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(httpRequestFactory()));
            restTemplate.getInterceptors().add(new LoggingClientHttpRequestInterceptor());
            return restTemplate;
        }
    
        @Bean
        public LocalValidatorFactoryBean restValidator() {
            return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try moving the `@ImportResource` annotation to a separate configuration class annotated with a [@Profile](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html) annotation, e.g:

```
@Profile("!Test")
@Configuration
@ImportResource("spring/*.xml")
class ResourceConfiguration {}
```

Comment: But I have to check if any profile is active and after that I decide which resource use. I have another folder called spring-test that contains sync mode and I have to execute that folder instead of the spring/*xml.